# How to pass JSON body using node to call REST service?

Tags: node.js

I am using a node.js and spring web services. I have spring web service application deployed on tomcat server and node is running. I am using a web application which will call node and from node I am calling Spring REST web service. I am able to get the JSON data in to the node but while calling from node to Spring REST web service I am getting following error:

```
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.createModelAndView(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:87)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:74)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:24)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.handle(ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.java:39)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.project.webservices.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2691)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169)
    ... 37 more
```

following is my node.js code:

```
    var express = require("express"), 
    app = express(), 
    http = require("http").createServer(app);
    var requestObj = require('request');  

    var responseBody = "";

    app.use(express.bodyParser());

    function getSample(token){
        requestObj({
                url : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/sample/get",
                method : "POST",
                headers : { "Content-Type" : "application/json","pubKey":token}
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                responseBody=body;
            }
        );
        console.log("responseBody:= "+responseBody);
    }

    function something(token,jsonbody){
        console.log("jsonbody :- "+JSON.stringify(jsonbody));
        requestObj({
                url : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/something/childurl",
                method : "POST",
                headers : { "Content-Type" : "application/json","pubKey":token},
                bosy : JSON.stringify(jsonbody)
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                responseBody=body;
            }
        );
        console.log("responseBody:= "+responseBody);
    }

    app.post('/samples', function(request, response){
        console.log(request.body);
        var methodName = request.method;
        var token = request.body.pubKey;
        console.log("Called method is :-"+methodName);
        if(methodName=="POST"){
            getSample(token);
        }
        response.send(responseBody);
    });


    app.post('/something', function(request, response){
        console.log(request.body);
        var methodName = request.method;
        var token = request.body.pubKey;
        console.log("Called method is :-"+methodName);
        if(methodName=="POST"){
            something(token,request.body);
        }
        response.send(responseBody);
    });


    app.listen(8088);
```

Comment: Seems you have a typo: "bosy : JSON.stringify(jsonbody)" -> "body : …"

Comment: I edited the same, but the error still persist. I am still not able to get in to the web service call and getting the same above error. 
Also one more thing I just looked in to the server logs actually I am passing a JSON and set content type as "application/json" but in response it is showing me "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" (This response is through the RESTClient add on of firefox) and if I am calling the REST URL directly using RESTClient tool without the node.js then it will return me response and will execute the code inside that REST web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `something()` you are missing `body:` param. As well, if you have json payload and response, you should use `json:true`.

```
requestObj({
                url : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/something/childurl",
                method : "POST",
                headers : { "Content-Type" : "application/json","pubKey":token},
                body : JSON.stringify(jsonbody),
                json: true
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                responseBody=body;
            }
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and pointing out the typo. But the error still persist. I am still not able to get in to the web service call and getting the same above error.

Comment: Also one more thing I just looked in to the server logs actually I am passing a JSON and set content type as "application/json" but in response it is showing me "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" (This response is through the RESTClient add on of firefox) and if I am calling the REST URL directly using RESTClient tool without the node.js then it will return me response and will execute the code inside that REST web service.

Comment: are you able to debug java part? it will be nice to see, do you hit target controller/action or something wrong with input. unfortunatelly I'm not aware of tomcat/springmvc so logs does not say much..

Comment: The request itself wont reach to Java because it is not able to detect/find the requested resource and if I am trying to call the samples it is able to execute the java code inside the controller, because that REST URL does not require body. I am more interested in passing json body. I added your changes in my code but I am not able to get in to the execution of controller method call. It will be great if there is any other way to send json body from node.js to REST web service.

Comment: I got the solution for this one the setting attribute on node side is I guess issue. Now I am able to call my REST web service call and also able to execute the code and return the result from the REST.